# All HTML i write is becoming linked (without using hrefs)?

Tags: html, css

This is the the code that I'm using. Everything below MSN.com becomes a link for some reason. I've checked my CSS and i assume the problem is there but wanted to first see if there is something going on where it is coming from the HTMl side?

```
<a href="http:msn.com" target="blank"><img class="makeBlock" src="images/scenery.jpg" alt="This is a clickable image"></a><br><br>
<!-- One way to utilize this functionality is to have a nice image button saved and use that to link to stuff -->

<!-- An array of images that are thumbnail size that be clicked to go to a new window for the bigger version -->
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="blank"><img src="images/scenery.jpg" alt="thumbnail size to link" width="width 52" height="70">
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="blank"><img src="images/scenery.jpg" alt="thumbnail size to link" width="width 52" height="70">
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="blank"><img src="http://freeforcommercialuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/msp_1701_4269.jpg" alt="thumbnail size to link" width="width 52" height="70">
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="blank"><img src="images/scenery.jpg" alt="thumbnail size to link" width="width 52" height="70">
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="blank"><img src="images/scenery.jpg" alt="thumbnail size to link" width="width 52" height="70">
<a href="http://google.com" target="blank"><img src="images/scenery.jpg" alt="thumbnail size to link" width="width 52" height="70">

<br>
<br>

</div>

<!-- The below is to create an image map using coordinats so people can click on different areas and go different places -->

<img src="http://freeforcommercialuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/msp_1701_4269.jpg" usemap="#scenery">
<map name="scenery">
<area shape="rect" alt="Left side strong side" coords="0,10,536,614" href="https://nba.com" target="blank">
</map>

<!-- An unordered list is called a bullet list. An ordered list is with numbers -->

<ul>
    <li>Sun</li>
    <li>Moon</li>
    <li>Test</li>
</ul>

<ol>
    <li>Ordered Sun</li>
    <li>Ordered Moon</li>
    <li>Ordered Test</li>
</ol>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Apples R1C1</td>
        <td>Oranges R1C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pears R2C1</td>
        <td>Peaches R2C2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You missing closing tags for all of your anchor elements. The structure should look like this `<a></a>`.

Or using one of you examples

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="blank">
   <img src="images/scenery.jpg" alt="thumbnail size to link" width="width 52" height="70">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the `</a>` properly in your code.

Comment: Thanks! Jeez i knew it was something simple and i spent the past half an hour trying everything but that.

Answer (score 0):

You are never closing your a elements with `</a>`.